# Как добавлять кнопки в клавиатуру в зависимости от данных из базы данных? Aiogram

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram

Пишу реферального бота, встал вопрос о добавлении динамических кнопок(которые меняются в зависимости от того, сколько групп зарегистрировано в базе данных) и никак не могу понять как их добавлять.
Из базы данных я получаю вот такие данные `{'Group name': 14314, '543': 53453}`

```
async def add_buttons():
    count = await DB.get_groups_count()
    for _ in range(count):
        data = await DB.get_groups()
        print(data)
        btn_text = data[0]
        btn_callback = data[1]
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=btn_text, url=btn_callback),
                     types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=btn_text, url=btn_callback))

        return keyboard
```

вот такой код я пытался сделать, но не понимаю как запускать в зависимости от количества групп в базе данных

Comment: Что лежит у вас в переменной count и в переменной data? Зачем вы ненужные запросы в БД, тем более в цикле делаете?

Comment: @MyZik в переменной count я пытался получить количество групп, чтобы как-то с ними взаимодействовать. А в переменной data лежит две группы {'Group name': 14314, '543': 53453}{'Group name': 14314, '543': 53453} для которых нужно сделать кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aiogram и вообще разработка Telegram-ботов тут не при чём, вы неправильно проходитесь по циклу, нужно так:

```py
for group in await DB.get_groups():
    btn_text = group[0]  # Group name
    btn_callback = group[1]  # 14314
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=btn_text, url=btn_callback),
                 types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=btn_text, url=btn_callback))

    return keyboard
```